Google sheets - data validation multiple arguments
Can you have multiple arguments in data validation for a cell?  e.g.
=NOT(ISBLANK(C2)) AND B2=1
Tried numerous functions and web searches without success. Everything that I have tried is not a valid expression. Can't find an answer.

Use the AND function.
=AND(NOT(ISBLANK(C2)),B2=1)

You could also use:
=AND(C2<>"",B2=1)

